# Highcharts Polar Chart - Make whole segment clickable / Change position of labels

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, graph, highcharts

I'm currently working on a Polar Chart that sits on top of the Google Map API. When you click a segment it zooms in, the polar chart disappears, and it shows the individual points within that segment. Here's a preview of it so far:

[image: Current polar chart]

Everything works as expected from a technical point of view, I just need to make a couple of modifications to make it more useable:

1) Is it possible to get it so a user can click anywhere within the segment to trigger the next stage. At the moment you have to click the blue areas meaning it's quite tricky to click the smaller portions, especially when they're overlaid with labels.

2) In the example above, you can see the y-axis labels are all a bit squashed when nearer the centre. Ideally they'd be centred within the middle of the segment. Is it possible to position them in the centre of each segment?

Any help appreciated on this. I've gone through pretty much every option in the documentation so am suspecting I need to go one step further and maybe look at modifying the DOM directly.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm guessing you will need to plot a transparent **[arc](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.arc())** in each sector right out to the full radius of the circle, and attach to it a click handler that triggers the click handler of the blue inner arc.

Comment: Have you any live example of this solution ?